# Why Set Symbols have a line with the alphabets?

Tags: calculus, notation

I was wondering that all the set symbols I have seen have a vertical line with them. e.g. the set of Real Numbers is represented by $\mathbb{R}$ this so why is there this line with the R. Can anybody answer?

Comment: It's just a notation that has become common. One of my teachers wrote a book on algebra, he denoted the real numbers with $\mathsf{C}$ and the integers with $\mathsf{I}$.

Comment: It's known as [blackboard bold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blackboard_bold). It originated as an approximation to writing a bold $\mathbf R$ on a blackboard.

Comment: Advanced Calculus, by Devinatz, uses  E for the reals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Historically, well before TeX, it was common for the set of real numbers and the set of integers to be handwritten as the letters R and Z, respectively, with a double line in them, something like this:

[image: R and Z handwritten]

The purpose was to identify these as "global constants" (although using that term from computer science is an anachronism), and to leave, for example, the unadorned letter R to be free for use to denote a relation.

As I recall, in print these were often just typeset as $\mathbf{R}$ and $\mathbf{Z}$ in regular boldface; the double-line versions were an attempt to simulate this boldface in handwritten symbols.

The double-line handwritten style was particularly common in blackboard use by professors, so the computer font in TeX inspired by this is called "blackboard bold".

By the way, one would occasionally see letters other than R or Z given this double-line treatment, but I don't believe those others were used as commonly; blackboard bold in TeX has become much more standardized, with such symbols as $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{C}$ in very common use and understood throughout the math community.

Comment: I would add that $\mathbb{T}$ is commonly used to denote the circle group; $\mathbb{H}$ and $\mathbb{O}$ for quaternions and octonions, respectively.

Comment: @lisyarus Thank you for the comment. I don't recall seeing those particular symbols used on the blackboard by professors back in the days before TeX, but I may just not have taken the right courses for that. I did see Q and C written with double lines occasionally; writing R and Z with double lines was nearly universal.

Comment: I didn't see these symbols used on the blackboard in the days before TeX too, since I even didn't exist :) I'm rather talking about modern notation in books, papers, and online sources.

Comment: @lisyarus Yes, the existence of blackboard bold font in TeX has made it much more common. I posted this answer mostly to try to contribute, in some small way, to a historical record of how and why our notation has evolved over time. History can disappear if old-timers (I guess I'm an old-timer now) don't document it.

Comment: Sure, the historical context is the proper answer to the question!